# I try to generate a featured image attached automatically to a post from an external url each time i publishing a post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, thumbnails

I'm trying to generate a featured image attached  automatically to a post from an external url each time i publishing a post.

I found a piece of php code that generates a featured image from the first image and I would like to do the same but with an external url, Can you help me find the best way to achieve this?

```
function set_first_as_featured($post_id){
    
    $medias = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id );
    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        foreach ($medias as $media) {
            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $media->ID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'set_first_as_featured');
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function :

```
function insert_attachment_from_url($url, $parent_post_id = null) {
    
        if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) )
            include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php' );
    
        $http = new WP_Http();
        $response = $http->request( $url );
        if( $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) {
            return false;
        }
    
        $upload = wp_upload_bits( basename($url), null, $response['body'] );
        if( !empty( $upload['error'] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    
        $file_path = $upload['file'];
        $file_name = basename( $file_path );
        $file_type = wp_check_filetype( $file_name, null );
        $attachment_title = sanitize_file_name( pathinfo( $file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    
        $post_info = array(
            'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $file_name,
            'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
            'post_title'     => $attachment_title,
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        );
    
        // Create the attachment
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $post_info, $file_path, $parent_post_id );
    
        // Include image.php
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    
        // Define attachment metadata
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file_path );
    
        // Assign metadata to attachment
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
        
        set_post_thumbnail( $parent_post_id, $attach_id );
    
        return $attach_id;
    
    }
```

call in your function

```
insert_attachment_from_url('YOUR_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_URL', $post_id);
```

Comment: Thanks @Moishy, ​​you gave me a great way, except apparently it automatically inserts the image before I even publish the article, I would like the image to be generated at the same time as the post. The code below works fine too except the image is not downloaded from the URL:

Comment: add_filter('admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'set_featured_image_from_attachment'); function set_featured_image_from_attachment($content) { global $post; if (has_post_thumbnail()) { // display the featured image $content = the_post_thumbnail() . $content; } else { $imgsrd = "<img src='auto-moto.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2022/02/…' alt='img'>"; $content = $imgsrd . $content; } return $content; }